# how to divide string and store into individual parts?

Tags: java, string

i have this String and i want to store each part is individual

```
String s="PN:VYZ,CPU:45,MEM:24,IO:93,CPU:39,MEM:2,IO:83,CPU:17,MEM:-2,IO:65,CPU:41,MEM:9";
```

like this :

`pn` ="VYZ"

`cpu0`=45

`MEM0`=24

`IO0`=93

`CPU1`=39
 ... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
class Demo{

 public static void main (String args[]){

   String x = "PN:VYZ,CPU:45,MEM:24,IO:93,CPU:39,MEM:2,IO:83,CPU:17,MEM:-2,IO:65,CPU:41,MEM:9";

   String []arr = x.split(",");

   System.out.println(arr[0]);  
   System.out.println(arr[1]);



 }

}
```